# Is there a better way to specify named arguments when calling in Python

Tags: python

`template.render(current_user=current_user, thread=thread, messages=messages)`

Is there a dont-repeat-yourself compliant way to do `whatever=whatever`? Like a magic symbol to prepend the variable name with or something like this `~whatever, ~something, ~etc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not.

For what it's worth, you can create a dictionary with your parameters and pass it with:

```
template.render(**parameters)
```

Note: You should always favor readability!

Comment: this, like AndiDogs answer, just shifts the repetition to the process of building the dict.

Comment: That is what I have been using, but I find it to be overkill when only a few arguments are used.

Comment: AFAICT: "No, there is not." seems to be the correct answer, gimmie a shot if I am wrong in ticking.

Answer (score 1):

If your `template.render()` method accepts any keyword arguments, and you don't mind passing it extra arguments that it won't use, then use:

```
template.render(**locals())
```

This will pass every local variable in under its own name.

Keep in mind that many people will object to the sloppiness implicit in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass keyword arguments from a dictionary if you want.

```
def a(b, c, d):
    pass

someArgs = {"b" : 1, "c" : 2, "d" : 3}
a(**someArgs)
```

If you want to prepend something to the variable names, you can change the dictionary keys:

```
a(**dict(("prefix_" + k, v) for k, v in someArgs.items()))
```

And as an aside, you know that you can't specify arguments called "~arg" in your source code?!

Comment: I used `~arg` as an example of something I am looking for, put a symbol before a variable name `~arg` would be the hypothetical equivalent of `arg=arg`.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of like aaronasterling's idea, but obviously it's not quite short.  suppose you have a naming convention for local variables.  variables that will be passed to the call have one naming style and everything else follows a different convention.  For instance, suppose you just say that the leading character of 'private' locals begin with an underscore.  thus:

```
def localargs (kwargs):
    return dict((k, v) for (k, v) in kwargs.iteritems() if k[0] != '_')

def somefunction(public_arg, _private_arg):
    public_local = "foo"
    _private_local = "bar"
    ...
    template.render(**localargs(locals()))
```

*but* that's hideous, don't do that.

Comment: I was thinking about doing it up in a function but decided not to. As it stands, your solution will crash if passed to a function that has a long list of keyward args but doesn't specify a `**` parameter. The solution is to have `localargs` take a(n optional) list of names and only pull those out of `locals()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a decorator, inspired to some degree by the one in a recipe titled [*Keyword Argument Injection with Python Decorators*](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577382-keyword-argument-injection-with-python-decorators/?c=11325), that might help. It certainly cuts down on the repetition, maybe too much.

```
import sys

def injectlocalargs(inFunction):

    def outFunction(*args, **kwargs):
        # get decorated function's argument names
        func_argnames = inFunction.func_code.co_varnames

        # caller's local namespace
        namespace = sys._getframe(1).f_locals

        # add values of any arguments named in caller's namespace
        kwargs.update([(name,namespace[name]) for name in func_argnames if name in namespace])

        # call decorated function and return its result    
        return inFunction(*args, **kwargs)

    return outFunction

##### testbed #####

class template_class:
    @injectlocalargs
    def render(self, extra_stuff, current_user, thread, messages):
        print 'render() args'
        print '  extra_stuff:%s, current_user:%s, thread:%s, messages:%s' % (extra_stuff, current_user, thread, messages)

def test():
    current_user = 'joe'
    thread = 42
    messages = ['greetings',"how's it going?"]
    template = template_class()

    template.render('extra_stuff')

test()
```

Output:

```
render() args
  extra_stuff:extra_stuff, current_user:joe, thread:42, messages:['greetings', "how's it going?"]
```